# ShapelyDeprecationWarnings and the use of "geoms"

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

Some lines to look up geographical information by given pair of coordinates, referenced from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254869/projecting-google-maps-coordinate-to-lookup-country-in-shapefile.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

pt = Point(8.7333333, 53.1333333) 

# countries shapefile from 
# http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php
folder = 'C:\\My Documents\\'

data = gpd.read_file(folder + 'TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp')

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    poly = row['geometry']
    if poly.contains(pt):
        print (row)


#  ---------- Print out as -----------------------------------
FIPS                                                        GM
ISO2                                                        DE
ISO3                                                       DEU
UN                                                         276
NAME                                                   Germany
AREA                                                     34895
POP2005                                               82652369
REGION                                                     150
SUBREGION                                                  155
LON                                                      9.851
LAT                                                      51.11
geometry     (POLYGON ((8.710255000000018 47.69680799999997...
Name: 71, dtype: object
```

It works but prints out paragraphs of ShapelyDeprecationWarnings:

```
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\inference.py:384: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms` property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.
  iter(obj)  # Can iterate over it.
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\inference.py:385: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: __len__ for multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Check the length of the `geoms` property instead to get the  number of parts of a multi-part geometry.
  len(obj)  # Has a length associated with it.
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\printing.py:120: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms` property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.
  s = iter(seq)
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\printing.py:124: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: __len__ for multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Check the length of the `geoms` property instead to get the  number of parts of a multi-part geometry.
  for i in range(min(nitems, len(seq)))
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\printing.py:128: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: __len__ for multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Check the length of the `geoms` property instead to get the  number of parts of a multi-part geometry.
  if nitems < len(seq):
```

To update the above code to avoid ShapelyDeprecationWarnings, I've tried to replace "for index, row in data.iterrows()" to "for index, row in data.geoms", and "poly = row['geometry']" to "poly = row.geoms". Neither worked.

What's the right way to update the code to avoid ShapelyDeprecationWarnings?

Comment: does `data.loc[data.contains(pt)]` achieve a similar result without the loop?

Comment: @PaulH, thanks for the comment. I tried "data.loc[data.contains(pt)]". It prints out many pair of coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data contains POLYGONs and MULTIPOLYGONs. Apparently there have been changes to Shapely's MULTIPOLYGON API which have not been fully integrated into GeoPandas yet.

```
data.geometry
```

```
> 0      MULTIPOLYGON (((-61.68667 17.02444, -61.88722 ...
> 1      POLYGON ((2.96361 36.80222, 4.78583 36.89472, ...
> ...
```

The mentioned errors appear when a MULTIPOLYGON is printed.

**Solution**

Exclude the `geometry` column when printing a row:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

pt = Point(8.7333333, 53.1333333) 

# countries shapefile from 
# http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php
# data = gpd.read_file('file.shp')

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    poly = row['geometry']
    if poly.contains(pt):
        print(data.drop(columns='geometry')
                  .iloc[[row.name]]
                  .iloc[0])
```

---

**Old answer**

The `geoms` property only exists on MULTIPOLYGONS.

Thus you have to adjust your code to deal with this accordingly:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():

    results = []    

    if hasattr(row.geometry, "geoms"):
        for part in row.geometry.geoms:
            if part.contains(pt):
                results.append(row)
                
    elif row.geometry.contains(pt):
        results.append(row)
        
    else:
        pass

    for row in results:
        print(data.drop(columns='geometry').iloc[[row.name]].iloc[0])
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I've tried your answer and it outputs many pairs of coordinates. However by the use of codes, I wish to print out the Country, Region, Sub-Region etc of the given coordinates. Can you please help me again?

Comment: You're welcome! Oh sorry, my bad. I updated my answer and even found a better solution!

Comment: amazing! thanks again for the brilliant answer that benefits lots of people!